# UpdatePanel.Update() command generates a full Page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Update Panel inside a User Control i use on 2 pages in my website
Both pages use the same MasterPage, ScriptManger is declared in the MasterPage.
Both pages call the UC the same way:

```
<uc:SearchCube runat="server" ID="searchCube" />
```

in the Update panel i have many RadioButtons that on change generate a server side event that fill dropdown in the update panel and update the panel

```
protected void SearchCategoryChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDropdowns();
    SearchOptions.Update();
}
```

Update Panel is  set like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchOptions" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
hildrenAsTriggers="true"/>
```

Each RadioButton is set like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="SearchCategory" runat="server"
AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="SearchCategoryChanged" Text="Text"/>
```

I also have an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` on each Radio Button Controller

The problem i have is that on one page when i call the `Update()` function the panel is updated and `Page_Load` is triggered which causes the UC to refresh and reload the default settings of the UC
I can see in DEBUG mode that on the working page `Update()` does not generate `Page_Load`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Your radio-buttons already are doing partial postback, why are u calling UpdatePanel.Update as well?

Comment: Because i need to refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a request goes to the server, it executes the `Page_Load` event.

What you need to do is make sure you have a PostBack validation on all your pages:

```
protectec void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Not a postBack: Normal page load
        //Init your page here
    }
    else
    {
        //It's a PostBack (from a command).
        //Do nothing or init stuff your all your commands.
    }
}
```

If you put some breakpoints in your `Page Load` and your `SearchCategoryChanged` method, you'll be able to see what the pipeline looks like.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, Thanks for your comment. i do have a PostBack validation and i can see that at first the page_load is executed on change but the problem i'm facing is that after the page_load and the the Update() function occurs another Page_Load that a IsPostBack = FALSE.

Comment: Are all your controls in the `UpdatePanel`? I mean the RadioButtons and your UserControls? The controls doing the postback AND the control being modified need to be into the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Yes. as i already wrote here the UC is works perfectly on one page but not on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem.
the problematic page is an index page that takes a few parameters in.
I have a Response.Redirect() on the page to avoid duplication of pages.
Apparently when the PostBack() is made it calls the page without any parameters and i was forcing it to be redirected into a default view since no parameters were sent to the page.

i found a lead to my problem in a Microsoft help forum that stated:

> By calling Response.Write() directly you are bypassing the normal
>   rendering mechanism of ASP.NET controls. The bits you write are going
>   straight out to the client without further processing (well,
>   mostly...). This means that UpdatePanel can't encode the data in its
>   special format.

Anyway the page was reloading every time which caused it to reload the User Control with it's default values.